# Keeping leading zeros using RODBC

Tags: r, leading-zero

I am trying to import data from an Access database into R.  I would like to import the CIP codes for some majors, which can contain leading zeros. RODBC is converting the CIP code to a numeric value even though it is defined as text in Access.  Can anyone shed light on how I can coerce this field into a text field on import?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the argument `as.is = TRUE` in the `sqlQuery` function. That usually does the trick for me.

Comment: That almost does the trick.  I tried that and it then made all of the columns into character types, including the dates and factors.  
  
I did the following instead (the CIP codes are the first 4 fields) and that did the trick.  
  
`df <- sqlFetch( conn, "tbl", as.is=c(rep(TRUE,times=4),rep(FALSE,times=32)))`

Answer (score 1):

```
library(RODBC)
channel=odbcConnectAccess2007("plz.accdb")
plz = sqlQuery(channel,"SELECT * from PLZ",as.is=TRUE)
```